# Не говори «прощай»/прощай

Tags: кавычки

Нужны кавычки в песне, о которой я в предыдущем вопросе говорил?

> Только не говори им прощай.

> Только не говори им «прощай».

> Только не говори им «Прощай».

Comment: Элементарно; нужны конечно.